# Как показать элемент без возможности посмотреть его в исходниках страницы до показа?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как показать/скрыть элемент без возможности посмотреть его в исходниках страницы?
Если делать возможность показывания/скрытия элемента через javascript, указывая значения block/none свойства display, то содержимое данного элемента можно посмотреть без задействования js кода через, например, исходник страницы.
А нужно чтобы содержимое элемента можно было посмотреть ТОЛЬКО, например, нажатием на кнопку, и БЕЗ перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: При клике на кнопку, делается запрос/формируется DOM, вставляется в нужный элемент, по закрытию удаляется. Итог: элемент пустой, или даже не существует, а создается только при клике на кнопку с последующим заполнением.

Comment: `!!! --->>> AJAX <<<--- !!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAXом делать запрос по клику на кнопку, получать нужный код и вставлять его в нужное место DOM. Примерно так:

```
function onButtonClick(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "my.php",
    success: function(data){
      $('#paste-here').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Как только мы добавим элемент на страницу, его можно будет посмотреть в исходниках. Соответственно дальше скрывать его можно уже через display: none;

Comment: Звучит неплохо. Мне непонятно только, что делает строчка url: "my.php"('это оттуда будут браться данные?) и,если на пред. вопрос "нет", откуда данные появятся вместо data?

Comment: Да, отсюда мы получаем данные, которые потом вставляем в DOM. В простейшем случае строка, содержащая HTML-код

Comment: Вы пропустили запятую в конце 3-ей строки(url: "my.php").

Comment: Поправил, спасибо! )